# how to set the scope to a module?

Tags: angular, module

angular 12

let's say I have a project with this structure:

```
/todo/components/...
/todo/services/todos.service.ts
/todo/todos.module.ts
app.module.ts
app.component.ts
```

I want the todo.service.ts service to be ported only to /todo

/todo/services/todos.service.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: TodoModule })
export class TodosService {
```

/todo/todo.module.ts

```
  providers: [TodosService],
```

I get this error :
*Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'TodosStoreService' before initialization*

I tried this other solution by removing the injection in the service :

/todo/todos.module.ts

```
export class TodosService {
```

I have no error but in app.component, the injection is done on the service while I would like it to be available only in the todo module

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uf7zpe-module-service

Answer (score 0):

**TLDL:**
You should import your module in the service
`import { TodosModule } from '../todos.module'`

**Complete:**
Following the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/providers

> It's also possible to specify that a service should be provided in a
> particular @NgModule. For example, if you don't want UserService to be
> available to applications unless they import a UserModule you've
> created, you can specify that the service should be provided in the
> module:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModule } from './user.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: UserModule,
})
export class UserService {
}
```

> The example above shows the preferred way to provide a service in a
> module. This method is preferred because it enables tree-shaking of
> the service if nothing injects it. If it's not possible to specify in
> the service which module should provide it, you can also declare a
> provider for the service within the module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {
}
```

Comment: that's what I did and I got this error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'TodosStoreService' before initialization

Comment: So, try to put it on stackblitz.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uf7zpe-module-service?file=src/app/todo/todo.module.ts

Comment: so I want the service: TodoService to be ported to the module: TodoModule